# How can I round numbers inside string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a string formatted as follows:

```
a 582 320 b 15.33 320 15.33 c 148.66 320 148.66
```

And I need all the numbers to be integers, as follows:

```
a 582 320 b 15 320 15 c 149 320 149
```

I was thinking to split the string on space, `parseFloat()` then `Math.Round()` with a `try` on each element then build the string back up again.

Any better/easier ways to do this?

Comment: Your idea sounds like the way to go. There is as far as I know, no shortcut to RoundNumbersInString(), rightfully so.

Comment: One problem is that `parseFloat()` will not throw exception, instead, it will just return `NaN`. So you should use `isNaN()` to check that the input can be translated as number or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex and a callback for rounding.

```js
console.log('a 15.33 320 15.33 c 148.66 148.66 999.999'.replace(/\d*\.\d*/g, function (v) {
    return Math.round(v);
}));
```

Comment: This was exactly the idea I had right after posting, I was researching this path. :)

Answer (score 0):

Might be even a (long) one-liner :-)

```
yourstring = yourstring.split(" ").map(function(el) {var p=parseFloat(el);return isNaN(p)?el:Math.round(p)}).join(" ")
```

Comment: You can make it shorter with ES6 `yourstring = yourstring.split(" ").map(e=>parseFloat(e)?Math.round(e):e).join(" ")`

Answer (score 0):

```
function roundNumbersInString(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) {
        return (/^[0-9.]+$/.test(txt)) ? Math.round(txt) : txt;
    });
}
console.log(roundNumbersInString("a 582 320 b 15.33 320 15.33 c 148.66 320 148.66"));
```

//"a 582 320 b 15 320 15 c 149 320 149"

Comment: You can chcek now. there was mistake in comment line.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would do this job.

```js
var str = "a 582 320 b 15.33 320 15.33 c 148.66 320 148.66",
 rndStr = str.split(" ").map(e => Math.round(+e) || e).join(" ");
console.log(rndStr);
```